# Outlook 2016 on Remote Desktop Server crashes when creating new profile

Tags: crash, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have created a couple of new users and when starting Outlook for the first time, all seems to work ok up to "Searching for xx@yy.com settings". Outlook then crashes with the following detail. Next attempt to start Outlook results in a message 
"Outlook cannot log on. Verify you are connected to the network and are using the proper server and mailbox name. The Microsoft Exchange information service in your profile is missing required information. Modify your profile to ensure that you are using the correct Microsoft Exchange information service."

When the autoconfig failure dialog is dismissed, a second dialog box appears stating "System resources are critically low. Close some windows." Less than half of the available RAM is in use and no other users are logged on.
Environment is Server 2012 R2 with RDS role enabled running in Hyper-V VM.

About a dozen existing users have no issue with Outlook 2016. These users were autoconfigured. 
Single Exchange 2016 is on-premises. 
Autoconfigure test initiated inside working profile is all ok.
sfc /scannow shows no errors.
Office repair completed.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: rundll32.exe
  Application Version:  6.3.9600.17415
  Application Timestamp:    545045a2
  Fault Module Name:    olmapi32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 16.0.4549.1002
  Fault Module Timestamp:   592963d3
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0016f481
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: 0b4d
  Additional Information 2: 0b4da1e2041abdb53aa72466f8cd7aea
  Additional Information 3: 167c
  Additional Information 4: 167c9fa52a18dcea7b92dde2113e020

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the following:

- An antivirus is causing a crash, try to remove that and then check it again
- A possible [known MS Outlook bug when using a proxy server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3119083/outlook-2016-crashes-when-creating-a-new-profile)
- Version 16.0.4549.1002 means you are on [13 June update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191932/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoutlook2016june13-2017), try the latest one
- Generall issues with the AutoDiscover process e.g. local hostfiles or some hardcoded redirects (see more infos [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/267-speed-up-the-exchange-outlook-autodiscovery-process.html))
- A IPS is blocking the connection. Check if you can do a telnet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Outlook 2016, and when adding a new account through Mail in Control Panel then `rundll32` would crash.

The problem, bizarrely, was hardware graphics acceleration.  In Word I went to File, Options, Advanced, Display (heading), then ticked "Disable hardware graphics acceleration".  This seems to change the option for all of Office, not just Word.

After this (even without exiting Word), I could immediately add a new e-mail account through Mail in Control Panel, with no `rundll32` crash!

Found the solution [on a Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/rundll32-outlook-mail-windows-host-process-error/bf90e1fd-3985-4b15-bc50-f9b3e937a859?tm=1424345216297).